# Angular 2 io.socket.on

Tags: socket.io, angular, sails.js

currently I'm working with angular 2 with sails.js and I have a problem with asynchrome event.
I have tried to use promise but the view doesn't change when the post array are updated, anyone has an idea ?

thank you for yours anwers.

```
    @Injectable()
export class newsService {
    posts = [];
    constructor() {
        console.log('newsService constructor');
        io.socket.on('post',event => { 
            let data = event.data;
            switch(event.verb) {
                case 'created':
                    let post = new Post();
                    post.id = data.id;
                    post.content = data.content;
                    post.author = data.author.fullname;
                    post.date = new Date(data.date);
                    this.posts.push(post); 
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess socket does run outside Angulars zone and therefore Angular doesn't recognize callbacks and doesn't run change detection. Run the code that updates the model inside Angulars zone explicitely like:

```
@Injectable()
export class newsService {
    posts = [];
    constructor(private zone:NgZone) {
        console.log('newsService constructor');
        io.socket.on('post',event => { 
          this.zone.run(() => {
            let data = event.data;
            switch(event.verb) {
                case 'created':
                    let post = new Post();
                    post.id = data.id;
                    post.content = data.content;
                    post.author = data.author.fullname;
                    post.date = new Date(data.date);
                    this.posts.push(post); 
                    break;
            }
          });
        });
    }
}
```